# Subquery in sql to solve problems displaying name in exactly 2 subjects

Tags: mysql

to display the name of all the candidates who got below 40  in exactly 2 subjects using sql

degree(degcode,name,subject)
candidate(seatno,degcode,name)
marks(seatno,dedcode,mark)

Comment: What methods have you tried?  Can we have the code that you've attempted, but doesn't work?

Comment: Here's a start ...  Research `INNER JOIN`  It'll look something like this: --> `SELECT *
FROM candidates
INNER JOIN degree ON degree.degcode = Ddecode.id`

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be like below-

```
SELECT cd.name 
FROM degree dg 
JOIN candidate cd ON cd.degcode=dg.degcode 
JOIN marks mk ON mk.seatno=cd.seatno 
WHERE mk.mark < 40 
GROUP BY cd.seatno 
HAVING COUNT(dg.degcode)=2;
```

If it does not work for you then can create a sqlfiddle with dummy data for more clairty so that I can modify query as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks .i tried sql fiddle but it seems that  it is not recognising the '.'  operator and moreover want a solution using subquery.